# How edit while loop to read a word once and increment the word from a file

Tags: c++

I am writing a code in visual studio 2010 win 32 console. In short the function should read from a file then use a loop to read each word in the file and increment the same words if it comes across a word that is already seen

i have tried to use a while loop to loop through the file but it only display all the words and does not increment words that are the same

```
list<TokenCount> buildUnigram_Model(char* fromfile)
{
    list<TokenCount> FT;
    ifstream inF;
    inF.open(fromfile,ios::in);
    string word;
    int frequency=0;
    while(inF>>word)
    {
        TokenCount C;
        initTokenCount(C,word,frequency);
        FT.push_back(C);
    }
    inF.close();
    return FT;
}
```

the expected result show be displayed on standard output as the word and the number of times each word appears eg if the file has "hi" five times then on standard output it should be    "hi        5"

Comment: This might be because nothing in the shown code appears to increment, or count anything. Which part of the shown code you expect to increment a given word's count? And nothing in the shown code seems to print a count of anything.

Comment: This doesn't address the question, but get in the habit of initializing objects to the value that they're going to have rather than default constructing them then modifying them. That is, change `ifstream inF; inF.open(fromfile,ios::in);` to `ifstream inF(fromfile);`. (Since it's an `ifstream`, it does input; you don't need to tell it `ios::in`). And you don't need to call `inF.close();`. The destructor will do that.

Comment: -Sam Varshavchik i dont know how to increment the word otherwise i have the code to display it works fine if the is an idea to increment it would be of great help sir

Comment: @Pete Becker i understand but if i am ask of an idea to increment the words in the file if two word are the same

Comment: Store the count in a std::map. What are `TokenCount` or `initTokenCount`?

Comment: well token count is a struct and inittokencount is the declaration function to store the words as they are being read thank you @ThomasSablik

Answer (score 0):

Store the count in a std::map.

```
std::map<std::string, std::size_t> count; 
while(inF>>word) ++count[word];
```